# foldrImpl and proofs

Tags: fold, proof, idris, dependent-type

I've been using the Vect datatype a lot in my code. Frequently, I find myself having to prove something involving library functions over Vects which use foldr. Since foldr is implemented on top of foldrImpl, if I try to inspect the proof context by putting a hole that is what shows up in the goal. My issue is that it doesn't seem like idris can evaluate the foldrImpl in the goal type (similar behavior to when a function is not known to be total by the totality checker), what makes me get stuck on the proofs.

Usually my solution to this problem is to define my own version of a library function that does the folding from scratch. But that is clearly inconvenient since: (i) I have to code the functions that already exist in the library; (ii) this make me not use fold in any definitions that I intend to later prove something about.

For a concrete example, consider that I want to prove the following

```
lemma_take_head : {x : a} -> 
                  {xs : List a} -> 
                  {ls : Vect len (List a)} ->  
                   concat ((x :: xs) :: ls) = x :: (concat (xs :: ls))
lemma_take_head {ls = []} = Refl
lemma_take_head {ls = l :: ls} = ?h2
```

With my version of concat, this is as easy as just returning Refl. But with the library version, which folds, we get the following context for the case when the Vect is topmost a cons:

```
  a : Type
  l : List a
  x : a
  xs : List a
  len : Nat
  ls : Vect len (List a)
--------------------------------------
h2 : foldrImpl (\meth, meth => meth ++ meth) [] (\x1 => x :: xs ++ l ++ x1) ls = x :: foldrImpl (\meth, meth => meth ++ meth) [] (\x1 => xs ++ l ++ x1) ls
```

Is there a way to continue proofs once they get to a point like this, or is the only solution to re-implement the functions in a way that they don't use folds?